# Simple fadeIn with ng-Animate and animate.css

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

So I've recently started learning angularJS and wanted to understand how you do animations. I do have experience with jQuery and know how easy it is to implement animation with it however with angular...not so much.

Anyways the code looks like this:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/indexCtrl.js"></script>
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="css/animate.css" type="text/css" href="">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="indexCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="i in vec">
        <div class="test1"><h1>{{i}}</h1></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html,body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
.test1{
    width: 100vw;
    height:10vh;
    text-align:center;
    background:red;
    margin-bottom:1vh;
}
.test1.ng-enter{
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

So what I want to learn is how to fadeIn the repeated elements.

Peace.

Comment: Have a look at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations

Comment: I think what you will find are two things (and I'm no CSS expert, but just from playing around with it I've discovered this): 1) unless it takes a long time to build the collection you are `ng-repeat`ing over the entire thing is going to be thrown out onto your view all at once which kind of negates the cool one-by-one fading in of your items and 2) the class has to go on the element with `ng-repeat`, not the child element as you have done in your question.

Comment: So I should try to attach the class,ng-enter that is, to the div that is repeating?